# Aspose pdf field validation in code

Tags: javascript, validation, acrobat, aspose.pdf

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro and Aspose PDF. Let's say I have a field in Acrobat where it contains a JavaScript code or in its format is restricted. 
When using Aspose PDF to fill this field, is there any method that Aspose provides to validate this field in code? (ie. some function that returns false if the value entered for a field is in wrong format)

Comment: My name is Tilal Ahmad and I am developer evangelist at Aspose. I am afraid currently requested feature is not supported in Aspose.Pdf. However we have logged an enhancement ticket PDFNET-41337 for same. You may follow [your post](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/771577/771297/showthread.aspx#771297) in Aspose.Pdf forum for further details.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick response